# How to correctly read csv in Pandas while changing the names of the columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

An absolute basic read_csv question.

### I have data that looks like the following in a csv file -

```
Date,Open Price,High Price,Low Price,Close Price,WAP,No.of Shares,No. of Trades,Total Turnover (Rs.),Deliverable Quantity,% Deli. Qty to Traded Qty,Spread High-Low,Spread Close-Open
28-February-2015,2270.00,2310.00,2258.00,2294.85,2279.192067772602217319,73422,8043,167342840.00,11556,15.74,52.00,24.85
27-February-2015,2267.25,2280.85,2258.00,2266.35,2269.239841485775122730,50721,4938,115098114.00,12297,24.24,22.85,-0.90
26-February-2015,2314.90,2314.90,2250.00,2259.50,2277.198324862194860047,69845,8403,159050917.00,22046,31.56,64.90,-55.40
25-February-2015,2290.00,2332.00,2278.35,2318.05,2315.100614216488163214,161995,10174,375034724.00,102972,63.56,53.65,28.05
24-February-2015,2276.05,2295.00,2258.00,2278.15,2281.058946240263344242,52251,7726,119187611.00,13292,25.44,37.00,2.10
23-February-2015,2303.95,2311.00,2253.25,2270.70,2281.912259219760108491,75951,7344,173313518.00,24969,32.88,57.75,-33.25
20-February-2015,2324.00,2335.20,2277.00,2284.30,2301.631421152326354478,79717,10233,183479152.00,23045,28.91,58.20,-39.70
19-February-2015,2304.00,2333.90,2292.00,2326.60,2321.485466301625211160,85835,8847,199264705.00,29728,34.63,41.90,22.60
18-February-2015,2284.00,2305.00,2261.10,2295.75,2282.060986778089405300,69884,6639,159479550.00,26665,38.16,43.90,11.75
16-February-2015,2281.00,2305.85,2266.00,2278.50,2284.961866239581019628,85541,10149,195457923.00,22164,25.91,39.85,-2.50
13-February-2015,2311.00,2324.90,2286.95,2296.40,2311.371235111317676864,109731,5570,253629077.00,69039,62.92,37.95,-14.60
12-February-2015,2280.00,2322.85,2275.00,2315.45,2301.372038211769425569,79766,9095,183571242.00,33981,42.60,47.85,35.45
11-February-2015,2275.00,2295.00,2258.25,2287.20,2279.587966250020639664,60563,7467,138058686.00,20058,33.12,36.75,12.20
10-February-2015,2244.90,2297.40,2225.00,2280.30,2269.562228214830293104,141656,13026,321497107.00,55577,39.23,72.40,35.40
```

--

I am trying to read this data in a pandas dataframe using the following variations of read_csv. I am only interested in two columns.

```
z = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date", usecols=["Date", "Open Price", "Close Price"], names=["Date", "O", "C"], header=0)
```

What I get is

```
     O    C

Date                
2015-02-28  NaN  NaN
2015-02-27  NaN  NaN
2015-02-26  NaN  NaN
2015-02-25  NaN  NaN
2015-02-24  NaN  NaN

Or 
z = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col="Date", usecols=["Date", "Open", "Close"], names=["Date", "Open Price", "Close Price"], header=0)
```

The result is -

```
    Open Price Close Price
Date                             
2015-02-28        NaN         NaN
2015-02-27        NaN         NaN
2015-02-26        NaN         NaN
2015-02-25        NaN         NaN
```

Am I missing something fundamental or is there an issue with read_csv of pandas `0.13.1` - my version on Debian Wheezy?

Comment: can you do it in two steps, read in the columns you want and then rename them?

Comment: Yes - I can do that - also there's something called a mapper on column names - eg I could do z.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_')). However that appears very convoluted. usecol and names together (with header=0) is actually quite intuitive.

Comment: Note that the two-steps approach is exactly what @Papouche's solution does.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are right, something is odd with the `name` attributes.  Seems to me that you can not use both in the same time. Either you set the name for every columns of the CSV file or you don't set the name at all. So it seems that you can't set the name when you are not taking all the colums (`usecols`)

`names : array-like
  List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None`

You might already know it but you can rename the colums after also.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

csv = r"""Date,Open Price,High Price,Low Price,Close Price,WAP,No.of Shares,No. of Trades,Total Turnover (Rs.),Deliverable Quantity,% Deli. Qty to Traded Qty,Spread High-Low,Spread Close-Open
28-February-2015,2270.00,2310.00,2258.00,2294.85,2279.192067772602217319,73422,8043,167342840.00,11556,15.74,52.00,24.85
27-February-2015,2267.25,2280.85,2258.00,2266.35,2269.239841485775122730,50721,4938,115098114.00,12297,24.24,22.85,-0.90
26-February-2015,2314.90,2314.90,2250.00,2259.50,2277.198324862194860047,69845,8403,159050917.00,22046,31.56,64.90,-55.40
25-February-2015,2290.00,2332.00,2278.35,2318.05,2315.100614216488163214,161995,10174,375034724.00,102972,63.56,53.65,28.05
24-February-2015,2276.05,2295.00,2258.00,2278.15,2281.058946240263344242,52251,7726,119187611.00,13292,25.44,37.00,2.10
23-February-2015,2303.95,2311.00,2253.25,2270.70,2281.912259219760108491,75951,7344,173313518.00,24969,32.88,57.75,-33.25
20-February-2015,2324.00,2335.20,2277.00,2284.30,2301.631421152326354478,79717,10233,183479152.00,23045,28.91,58.20,-39.70
19-February-2015,2304.00,2333.90,2292.00,2326.60,2321.485466301625211160,85835,8847,199264705.00,29728,34.63,41.90,22.60
18-February-2015,2284.00,2305.00,2261.10,2295.75,2282.060986778089405300,69884,6639,159479550.00,26665,38.16,43.90,11.75
16-February-2015,2281.00,2305.85,2266.00,2278.50,2284.961866239581019628,85541,10149,195457923.00,22164,25.91,39.85,-2.50
13-February-2015,2311.00,2324.90,2286.95,2296.40,2311.371235111317676864,109731,5570,253629077.00,69039,62.92,37.95,-14.60
12-February-2015,2280.00,2322.85,2275.00,2315.45,2301.372038211769425569,79766,9095,183571242.00,33981,42.60,47.85,35.45
    11-February-2015,2275.00,2295.00,2258.25,2287.20,2279.587966250020639664,60563,7467,138058686.00,20058,33.12,36.75,12.20
    10-February-2015,2244.90,2297.40,2225.00,2280.30,2269.562228214830293104,141656,13026,321497107.00,55577,39.23,72.40,35.40"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), 
        usecols=["Date", "Open Price", "Close Price"],
        header=0)

df.columns = ['Date', 'O', 'C']

df
```

output:

```
                Date        O        C
0   28-February-2015  2270.00  2294.85
1   27-February-2015  2267.25  2266.35
2   26-February-2015  2314.90  2259.50
3   25-February-2015  2290.00  2318.05
4   24-February-2015  2276.05  2278.15
5   23-February-2015  2303.95  2270.70
6   20-February-2015  2324.00  2284.30
7   19-February-2015  2304.00  2326.60
8   18-February-2015  2284.00  2295.75
9   16-February-2015  2281.00  2278.50
10  13-February-2015  2311.00  2296.40
11  12-February-2015  2280.00  2315.45
12  11-February-2015  2275.00  2287.20
13  10-February-2015  2244.90  2280.30
```

Comment: Yeah this appears quite simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

According to documentation your **usecols** list should be subset of new **names** list

```
usecols : list-like or callable, default None
Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or strings
that correspond to column names provided either by the user in `names` or
inferred from the document header row(s).
```

Example of csv

```
"OLD1", "OLD2", "OLD3"
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Code for renaming OLDX -> NEWX and using only NEW2 + NEW3

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, names=['NEW1', 'NEW2', 'NEW3'], usecols=['NEW2', 'NEW3'])
```

Output

```
   NEW2  NEW3
0     2     3
1     5     6
```

**NOTE:** Even if above is working as expected there is an issue while changing `engine='python'`

```
d = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, engine='python',
                names=['NEW1', 'NEW2', 'NEW3'], usecols=['NEW2', 'NEW3'])
```

`ValueError: Number of passed names did not match number of header fields in the file`

Workaround is set `header=None` and `skiprows=[0,]`:

```
d = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, skiprows=[0,], engine='python', names=['NEW1', 'NEW2', 'NEW3'], usecols=['NEW2', 'NEW3'])
```

Output

```
   NEW2  NEW3
0     2     3
1     5     6
```

***Pandas version: 0.23.4***